# Initialising New Label in code - crashes

Tags: vb.net, arrays, vb6, controls, vb6-migration

I'm converting an application from VB6 to VB.NET, and am required to declare and initialise some controls in code (control arrays). I have it declared globally, so other forms can access the data stored within them, and then I try to manipulate them inside the Form_Load() sub:

```
Public lblDataZone() As Label

Private Sub Form_Load() Handles Me.Load

    lblDataZone(0) = New Label

    With lblDataZone(0)
            .Height = 13
            .Text = "Zone (l/min)"
            .Left = 6
            .Top = 42
    End With
```

The error I get says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I feel like I'm missing something huge here, but what's wrong with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to instantiate the array of `Label`. You can use `ReDim()` or `New` keyword:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load() Handles Me.Load
    ReDim lblDataZone(0)   'Or lblDataZone = New Label(0) {}
    lblDataZone(0) = New Label
    With lblDataZone(0)
            .Height = 13
            .Text = "Zone (l/min)"
            .Left = 6
            .Top = 42
    End With
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first PUBLIC to allocate the array with the dimension needed, not just declare it:

```
Public lblDataZone(99) As Label

Private Sub Form_Load() Handles Me.Load

  lblDataZone(0) = New Label

  With lblDataZone(0)
        .Height = 13
        .Text = "Zone (l/min)"
        .Left = 6
        .Top = 42
  End With
```